# How pass activity to function in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am using "setCameraDisplayOrientation" function in this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html but I don't know how pass current activity to this function . can any body help me ? thx

Comment: So difficult to know your problem. Would you please parse some code into here?

Comment: Look whenever you need to pass an activity you can go by passing its context or you better use , YourActivityName.this

Comment: I have camera activity that use surface view and I want use setCameraDisplayOrientation function to display correct show and I need to pass current activity but I can't

Comment: I use MyActivityName.this but it's not work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Like This

`setCameraDisplayOrientation(this)` or

`setCameraDisplayOrientation(YourActivityName.this)`